# Check/verify if in Django template, there are real numbers in decimal places, and if zeros, round off

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I couldn't seem to find a specific answer for this question. So, my question differs based on two different scenarios:

(1) In my Django template, can I use some kind of filter to round real numbers in the decimal position, to only 2 digits, but still round any zeros to the nearest whole number/integer? (ie $1.25 and 1.00 would look like $1.25 and $1 respectively)

** Unfortunately, **|floatformat:2** includes the zeros

(2) If the above is not possible, is there some kind of conditional where I can check beforehand in the Django template if there are real numbers in the decimal position instead of zeros, and perform some kind of logic as a result?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: wrt/ point 2: Don't even try to code such logic in the template itself, write a custom template filter instead (this is dead simple, really).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [django template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/) if you need any custom operation to be done in Django.

OR

{{ value|floatformat:"-2" }} this may work in your case

Comment: Not sure if you read through my post, but I did use a django template tag, and it didn't work the way I wanted it to. I used floatformat.

Comment: Write a custom one as you required, write a custom template tag, since u need to remove only 0's alone, u can use any normal split method, compare and remove

Comment: Ok, will try that. Thank you.

Comment: Had to convert the value being passed in my custom filter to a float, but after that it worked perfectly. :D

Comment: Hey Thomas, is there a way to round off so if there is a zero in the first and second decimal position, it will round to the nearest integer, and if there is only one zero, and it is in the second decimal position, to keep it the same? (e.g. 1.50 would stay 1.50, but 1.00 would become 1)

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#floatformat @Dev Please try this out

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.